# wrangling a presents/absents table to long form in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I an new to R (and think I always be).
I am trying to wrangle the table resulting this code (only a very short example):

```
PlotA<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
PlotB<-c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)
PlotC<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)
PlotD<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)

DF<-as.data.frame(cbind(PlotA,PlotB,PlotC,PlotD))
row.names(DF)<-paste0("Species",LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )])
```

To this one (an example of only two plots out of the four):

```
SpeciesRepeat<-c("SpecisB","SpecisD","SpecisF","SpecisH","SpecisJ","SpecisC","SpecisD","SpecisG","SpecisH")
PlotRepeat<-c(rep("PlotA",length(PlotA [PlotA==1])), rep("PlotB",length(PlotB [PlotB==1])))
DesierdResDF<-cbind(SpeciesRepeat,PlotRepeat)
```

where every observation of a species in in a plot is represented in a row (obs).
tidyverse and basic R code will both be appreciated

Thanks,
Idan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with `tidyverse`. We first add a new column for rownames, get the data in long format and select rows where `value = 1`.

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>%
  rownames_to_column('SpeciesRepeat') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Plot"), names_to = 'PlotRepeat') %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(-value) 

# A tibble: 15 x 2
#   SpeciesRepeat PlotRepeat
#   <chr>         <chr>     
# 1 SpeciesB      PlotA     
# 2 SpeciesC      PlotB     
# 3 SpeciesD      PlotA     
# 4 SpeciesD      PlotB     
# 5 SpeciesE      PlotC     
# 6 SpeciesF      PlotA     
# 7 SpeciesF      PlotC     
# 8 SpeciesG      PlotB     
# 9 SpeciesG      PlotC     
#10 SpeciesH      PlotA     
#11 SpeciesH      PlotB     
#12 SpeciesH      PlotC     
#13 SpeciesI      PlotD     
#14 SpeciesJ      PlotA     
#15 SpeciesJ      PlotD
```

Comment: Got this: Error in pivot_longer(., cols = starts_with("Plot")) : 
  could not find function "pivot_longer"

Comment: @Idan you probably need to update `tidyr`. Do `install.packages('tidyr')`